# Cleaning vs Bathing

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag wiki for [cleaning](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleaning):

> Questions about cleaning your pet or the environment he/she lives in. Use this tag when your question addresses cleaning methods, requirements, and other aspects that pertain to keeping a clean atmosphere for your pet.

The tag wiki for [bathing](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bathing):

> The act of rendering a pet clean through shower or bath or scrubbing purposes; may also refer to a cat "bathing" itself via tongue.

I noticed a question had been using both, so when I looked at it, imagine my surprise when we had two tags referring to the act of cleaning a pet! What should we do with the tags?

Comment: Polling isn't really a good way to do this, I have to be honest. Aside from my immediate desire to vote up (or down, it's a whim) all the options, it discourages discussion. I think it's far better to ask the question and, if you have a desired outcome, put out the case for it. If there is a dissenter, let them make a case for the opposition.

Comment: @JohnCavan The problem is I don't have a desired outcome on this. Those were just the two options I could think of. I could delete them and mention them in my question if you think that'd work better.

Comment: Then just let the answers come. For example, see this one: http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/questions/159/should-we-clean-up-pooping-and-droppings?rq=1

Comment: Bathing is pet-specific. You bathe your pet, and that's really it. Cleaning seems to be more broad. You might have questions about cleaning the house before getting a new puppy, or cleaning a fish tank. I can see where there's an overlap, but I think both tags have distinct purposes.

Answer (score 3):

I see [bathing](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bathing) being a subset of [cleaning](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleaning) fairly readily, but there's a natural tendency for bathing to be related to living creatures and cleaning to inanimate ones. For example, you bath your dog and clean your car.

So, what I think it boils down to is a tweak to the [cleaning](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cleaning) wiki. There hasn't been overlap yet, which tends to support my thought that people will gravitate to the usage, so I would be inclined to keep them apart for now.

Answer (score 1):

We are far along enough now that we should be able to address these types of issues through the existing SE structure.

Make a suggestion, and everyone votes on it through the existing process.

https://pets.stackexchange.com/tags/cleaning/synonyms

**AND/OR**

https://pets.stackexchange.com/tags/bathing/synonyms

Comment: You do need to have some activity in a tag before you can propose or vote, so that's still a little iffy for the threshold right now on some less common tags.

Comment: That, and I don't have any real opinion on it being a synonym or not, just that if it isn't we should update one of the wikis.